# What are the strengths and weaknesses of being an S or T type?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

Each character can either be an S or T type, and those types will define which skills each character learns.

What are the strengths and weaknesses of being an S and T type per character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Lloyd:
S type cons - Less hits than T type, his artes are generally slower.
S type pros - Generally has higher damage per hit, often has superior crowd management, allows access to brave blade.
T type cons - Often does less damage per hit, many artes seem very linear.
T Type pros - Very large number of hits leading to higher combo possibility, fast.

Colette:
S type cons - Not as good at combo-ing, she doesn't learn Hammer Rain; so she cannot use Stardust Rain.
S type pros - Allows her to use Paraball, generally stronger artes.
T type cons - Does not allow access to Paraball, generally weaker artes.
T type pros - Allows acces to Hammer Rain and as a result Stardust Rain, decent comboability.

Genis:
S type cons - He gets less combined spells, he gets no light elemental spells.
S type pros - Allows access to Indignation and Indignation Judgement, generally better spells.
T type cons - He doesn't get access to Indignation or Indignation Judgement.
T type pros - He gets more combined spells and a light elemental spell.

Raine:
S type cons - Highly focused and generally worse, she doesn't get Revitalize.
S type pros - Some spells are superior at healing single targets.
T type cons - Less effective at healing single units in very rare occasions.
T type pros - Her spells effect a good range are more cost effective and she gets revitalise.

Sheena:
S type cons - Less damage.
S type pros - Superior at lowering the enemies stats.
T type cons - More damage.
T type pros - Inferior at lowering th enemies stats.

Kratos/Zelos:
S type cons - I cannot think of any currently.
S type pros - They get access to Light spear cannon and Grave blade.
T type cons - They don't get access to Light spear cannon and Grave blade.
T type pros - I cannot think of any currently.

Presea:
S type cons - They are generally worse than her T type artes.
S type pros - She gets a level three arte in her Devastation line.
T type cons - She does not get a level three arte in her Devastation line.
T type pros - She gets very powerful, cheap and wide ranged artes, it is generally the best ay to go for her.
```

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gamecube/561316-tales-of-symphonia/answers/203198-what-are-pros-and-cons-for-the-t-and-s-type-for-each-char)